# Import existing Android project, eclipse popup error msg

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent, eclipse-plugin

I git clone an Android project codebase into the workspace of my eclipse. Then I try to import the project as an existing Android project to my eclipse by choosing **File-->Import…** & import the Android project. But eclipse pop up the following error:

```
Cannot nest 'myapp/src/main/java' inside 'myapp/src'. To enable the nesting exclude 'main/' from 'myapp/src'
```

Why ?

Comment: It sounds like cyclic dependency in project folders. Have you tried to clone the project outside workspace/ and then import it inside?

Comment: try deleting the existing project and import a fresh copy....

Comment: Your suggestions don't help

Answer (score 0):

After recently working on a new  application project, it came to a stage where I had to download the project at home on my personal machine. So of course I logged into our SVN and grabbed a copy.

After getting the project there was an error in the project:

```
Cannot nest 'Project/src/main/java' inside library 'Project/src
```

I knew previously that this error wasn’t occuring. As far as the project classpath is concerned there was only one src path which correctly pointed at the folder Project/src/main/java

After searching through the project I found out the issue – in the .settings folder there is a file named:

```
    org.eclipse.wst.common.component
```

You should find you have a line similar to the following:

```
   <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src"/>
```

To fix simply remove that line (and if you don’t have it already, add the line):

```
   <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/java"/>
```

Comment: I don't have this file 'org.eclipse.wst.common.component' under .setting/